# Is there a maximum limit on the number of customer groups?

Tags: customer-group

Is there any upper limit on the number of customer groups in Magento CE?

Answer (score 3):

99999, if we follow the maximum index in the db. A large amount can influence performances as customer pages are most of the time not cached but else, I do not see any problem to set that amount.

Here is the creation script of the table. The customer_group_id is a smallint with a length of 5 so the maximum index is 99999.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_group` (
`customer_group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Group Id',
`customer_group_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Group Code',
`tax_class_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Tax Class Id'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customer Group' AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

ALTER TABLE `customer_group`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`customer_group_id`);

ALTER TABLE `customer_group`
MODIFY `customer_group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  COMMENT 'Customer Group Id',AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me in which file this written

Comment: you can find it in the customer_group table in you db. I edit my answer to complete it.